# how to make this sass work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have non-sass:

```
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
```

and want to do something like:

```
$radius_size: 4;

.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: #{$radius_size}px;
```

or

```
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: $radius_sizepx;
```

but these won't work. What is the syntax for this call?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of sass are you using? Your first example (`-moz-border-radius-topleft: #{$radius_size}px;`) should work. It does for me on 3.1.16.

Comment: `sass (3.1.15, 3.1.10, 3.1.8, 3.1.7)
sass-rails (3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.2, 3.1.0)`

Comment: wierd seems - to be working now; maybe an unrelated error

Comment: Cool. If you ever need to know the exact version of a gem you're using in your app, and are using bundler, you can do a `bundle show <gemname>`, e.g. `bundle show sass` and it will show the exact gem you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option (using interpolations) does look like it should work:

```
$radius_size: 4;
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: #{$radius_size}px;
}
```

Generally, though, I think it's best to store the units in the variable itself, since SASS will [automatically convert](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#number_operations) between units (if it can) when you use the variable in arithmetic expressions:

```
$radius_size: 4px;
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: $radius_size;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Also consider using [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). With it you can write:

```
$radius_size: 4px;
.rounded-corners {
  +border-top-left-radius($radius_size);
}
```

And this automatically produces:

```
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -ms-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
}
```